# save appconfig when it is in another file

Tags: c#, configuration, app-config

Hello I have my appconfig settings in a different file "settings.config" and it is linked like this in configuration file:

```
<appSettings file="../settings.config">
</appSettings>
```

I try to modify and save the appconfig settings at run time but only other settings from configuration file are saved.

```
System.Configuration.Configuration config = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration("../../../xyz.exe");    
AppSettingsSection appsettings = config.AppSettings;
appsettings.Settings["Key"].Value= "xyz";
config.Save(System.Configuration.ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```

Can somebody help me?